# Mocking azure file libraries for uploading a file from local to Azure File Storage

Tags: unit-testing, mockito, azure-storage, junit5

I have a service class where I have a method implementing upload functionality to Azure file storage using Azure storage libraries such as CloudStorageAccount,CloudFileClient etc. and where I'm passing connectionString,share name and directory name.

I'm trying to write a unit test using Junit and Mockito for the same method but not understanding how to mock the service without calling the actual upload method. I did write a test case with 100% coverage but the problem is its calling the actual method.

PS. I'm new to Junit and Mockito. Therefore, am really stuck on this one for a while now.
Any help is highly appreciated.

**This is my ReportUploadService class.**

```
@Service
@Log4j2
public class ReportUploadService {

    private final AzureFileProperties azureFileProperties;

    private static final String CONNECTION_STRING ="xyz...";
    private static final String SHARE_NAME = "abc";
    private static final String DIR_NAME = "test";

    @Autowired
    public ReportUploadService(AzureFileProperties azureFileProperties) {

        this.azureFileProperties = azureFileProperties;
    }

    public void uploadFile(String filePath) throws FileNotFoundException {
        try {
            var storageAccount = CloudStorageAccount.parse(CONNECTION_STRING);
            var fileClient = storageAccount.createCloudFileClient();
            var share = fileClient.getShareReference(SHARE_NAME);
            var rootDir = share.getRootDirectoryReference();
            var sampleDir = rootDir.getDirectoryReference(DIR_NAME);
            var cloudFile = sampleDir.getFileReference("testfile.txt");

            cloudFile.uploadFromFile(filePath);
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            log.error("File could not be uploaded", ex);
            throw new FileNotFoundException(ex.getMessage());
        }
    }`
```

**This is my test class.**

```
@ExtendWith(MockitoExtension.class)
class ReportUploadServiceTest {

    private ReportUploadService uploadService;

    @Mock
    private AzureFileProperties azureFileProperties;

    @Mock
    private CloudStorageAccount cloudStorageAccount;

    @Mock
    private CloudFileClient cloudFileClient;

    @Mock
    private CloudFileDirectory cloudFileDirectory;

    @Mock
    private CloudFileShare cloudFileShare;

    @Mock
    private CloudFile cloudFile;

    @BeforeEach
    void setUp() {

        this.uploadService = new ReportUploadService(azureFileProperties);
    }

@Test
void uploadFile() throws URISyntaxException, StorageException, IOException, InvalidKeyException {

    String shareName = "test-share";
    String dirName = "test-directory";
    String fileName = "testfile.txt";
    File file = new File("src/test/resources/testfile.txt");

    uploadService.uploadFile(file.getAbsolutePath());

    when(cloudStorageAccount.createCloudFileClient()).thenReturn(cloudFileClient);
    when(cloudFileClient.getShareReference(shareName)).thenReturn(cloudFileShare);
    when(cloudFileShare.getRootDirectoryReference()).thenReturn(cloudFileDirectory);
    when(cloudFileDirectory.getFileReference(fileName)).thenReturn(cloudFile);
    doNothing().when(cloudFile).uploadFromFile(file.getAbsolutePath());

    verify(cloudStorageAccount, times(1)).createCloudFileClient();
    verify(cloudFileClient, times(1)).getShareReference(shareName);
    verify(cloudFileShare, times(1)).getRootDirectoryReference();
    verify(cloudFileDirectory, times(1)).getDirectoryReference(dirName);
    verify(cloudFileDirectory, times(1)).getFileReference(fileName);
    verify(cloudFile, times(1)).uploadFromFile(file.getAbsolutePath());
}
```

This one failed with 87% coverage and following error:

Wanted but not invoked:

cloudStorageAccount.createCloudFileClient();

-> at com.microsoft.azure.storage.CloudStorageAccount.createCloudFileClient(CloudStorageAccount.java:1071)

Actually, there were zero interactions with this mock.

Answer (score 0):

I think that `CloudStorageAccount.parse(CONNECTION_STRING)` is not returning the cloudStorageAccount mock that you created and injected into the ReportUploadService instance. So you need to return somehow your mocked cloudStorageAccount. I have 3 options for you.

**The first one is to use mockito-inline for testing so the test should look like:**

```
@ExtendWith(MockitoExtension.class)
class ReportUploadServiceTest {

    @InjectMocks
    private ReportUploadService uploadService;

    @Mock
    private AzureFileProperties azureFileProperties;

    @Mock
    private CloudStorageAccount cloudStorageAccount;

    @Mock
    private CloudFileClient cloudFileClient;

    @Mock
    private CloudFileDirectory cloudFileDirectory;

    @Mock
    private CloudFileShare cloudFileShare;

    @Mock
    private CloudFile cloudFile;

    @Test
    void uploadFile() throws URISyntaxException, StorageException, IOException, InvalidKeyException {

        String shareName = "test-share";
        String dirName = "test-directory";
        String fileName = "testfile.txt";
        File file = new File("src/test/resources/testfile.txt");

        try(MockedStatic<CloudStorageAccount> tMockedStatic = mockStatic(CloudStorageAccount.class)) {

            tMockedStatic
                    .when(() -> CloudStorageAccount.parse(CONNECTION_STRING))
                    .thenReturn(cloudStorageAccount);

            when(cloudStorageAccount.createCloudFileClient()).thenReturn(cloudFileClient);
            when(cloudFileClient.getShareReference(shareName)).thenReturn(cloudFileShare);
            when(cloudFileShare.getRootDirectoryReference()).thenReturn(cloudFileDirectory);
            when(cloudFileDirectory.getFileReference(fileName)).thenReturn(cloudFile);
            doNothing().when(cloudFile).uploadFromFile(file.getAbsolutePath());
            uploadService.uploadFile(file.getAbsolutePath());

            tMockedStatic.verify(() -> CloudStorageAccount.parse(CONNECTION_STRING));
            verify(cloudStorageAccount, times(1)).createCloudFileClient();
            verify(cloudFileClient, times(1)).getShareReference(shareName);
            verify(cloudFileShare, times(1)).getRootDirectoryReference();
            verify(cloudFileDirectory, times(1)).getDirectoryReference(dirName);
            verify(cloudFileDirectory, times(1)).getFileReference(fileName);
            verify(cloudFile, times(1)).uploadFromFile(file.getAbsolutePath());
        }
    }
```

**The second one is to create non-static method and just return your static method like:**

```
public class ReportUploadService {

private final AzureFileProperties azureFileProperties;
private final CloudFileClient cloudFileClient;

public ReportUploadService(AzureFileProperties azureFileProperties, CloudFileClient cloudFileClient) {
    this.azureFileProperties = azureFileProperties;
    this.cloudFileClient = cloudFileClient;
}

public CloudStorageAccount getCloudStorageAccount() throws URISyntaxException, InvalidKeyException {
    return CloudStorageAccount.parse(CONNECTION_STRING);
}

public void uploadFile(String filePath) throws FileNotFoundException {
    try {
        var storageAccount = getCloudStorageAccount();
        var fileClient = storageAccount.createCloudFileClient();
        var share = fileClient.getShareReference(azureFileProperties.getShareName());
        var rootDir = share.getRootDirectoryReference();
        var sampleDir = rootDir.getDirectoryReference(azureFileProperties.getDirName());
        var cloudFile = sampleDir.getFileReference("testfile.txt");

        cloudFile.uploadFromFile(filePath);
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        log.error("File could not be uploaded", ex);
        throw new FileNotFoundException(ex.getMessage());
    }
}
```

}

and then you can mock this method in your test and return your mocked object.

**And the last one is to use Powermockito for mocking this static method**. I highly don't recommend it because Power Mock should be used in legacy applications where you cannot change the code which has been given to you. Often such code does not have unit/integration tests and even small changes can result in bugs in the application.

Comment: Thank you so much for your reply. I tried the first option which you suggested by using mockito-inline. Upon executing the test failed with following error:
Wanted but not invoked:
CloudStorageAccount.class.parse(
    "DefaultEndpointsProtocol=https;AccountName=audrilogdev;AccountKey=9hz62Iglm0VhrAFdlm/MygvrX3HBLav+4XE6MLXfzLsTD2pzSCLogN/GwGpczoGKXd0IB+bWpPf1+AStwiVbUg==;EndpointSuffix=core.windows.net"
);
-> at com.microsoft.azure.storage.CloudStorageAccount.parse(CloudStorageAccount.java:263)
Actually, there were zero interactions with this mock.

Comment: Did you add mockito-inline inside of mockito-core in maven dependency?

Comment: Add try to extract all when() and verify from try block) It might help

Comment: yes i've added the mockito-inline dependency. I didn't get  try to extract all when() part.
Could you please give an example of try to extract all when()? :)

Comment: Actually, I made a mistake. I have updated my answer.  Check now, please 1st option

Comment: I tried the first approach. But here the main task is instead of calling the actual method ie. uploadService.uploadFile(file.getAbsolutePath()); I need to mock the upload functionality and then use assertions. Thats where i'm actually stuck.

Comment: I have a doubt,do I need to use Mock annotation on the Service instance as well ? like this
@Mock private UploadService uploadService

Comment: When you are testing Service and want to inject all mocks to this Service you need to use '@InjectMocks' for this field. like: 
@InjectMocks
private ReportUploadService uploadService;
Note: You don't need to initialize Service then(remove before method and just use annotation)

Comment: Thank you for your reply. But how do I use assertions here?
Could you please give any idea on that as well

Comment: I created a chat for us. Join please https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/253494/mockito-testing

Comment: Actually I don't have enough reputation to continue on chat as I've just joined recently :)

Comment: Ohh, okey, what do you mean by assertion? like Assertion.functions? or injecting mocks into service?

Comment: yes..like after injecting the mocks into the service need to check if the file got uploaded or not using Assertions.functions

Comment: if I understood correctly. Use verify() as you did. I have updated code

Comment: No, I meant assertion like assertThat() or assertEqual(expected,actual) whether file exists or not.

Comment: The method is void, you can`t do it.